# Why doesn't my React Js form accept user input?

Tags: forms, reactjs

I have a simple `AddUser` component and in the `render` function I am returning the following html:

```
  <form ref="form" className="users-form" onSubmit={ this.handleAddNew }>
    <input ref="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"
        value={this.state.username} onChange={function() {}} /><br />
    <input ref="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"
        value={this.state.email} onChange={function() {}} /><br />
    <button type="submit"> Add User </button>
  </form>
```

I am binding the state of `username` and `email` to `this.state` which I am setting to blank in `getInitialState` like so:

```
getInitialState() {
   return { username: '', email: '' };
}
```

I am binding state to the form so I can set it to blank after form submission.

The problem with this setup is that **the form now renders as readonly**.

I cannot get any user input into either text fields. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your input fields are controlled components, since you are using the value property. This makes the inputs readonly and they will always reflect the value, the variable (in this case, the state variable) holds. You have to explicitly setState onChange since you are setting username field as a state variable.

Read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)

```
onUserNameChange : function(e){
    this.setState({username : e.target.value})
 },
 render: function(){
   return  ...
<input ref="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"
    value={this.state.username} onChange={this.onUserNameChange} /><br />
...
<button type="submit"> Add User </button>
</form>
 }
```

A better way to do this is :

```
onChange : function(field,e){
  this.setState({field: e.target.value});
}, 
render : function(){

return    <form ref="form" className="users-form" onSubmit={ this.handleAddNew }>
<input ref="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"
    value={this.state.username} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this,"username")}  /><br />
<input ref="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"
    value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this,"email")} /><br />
<button type="submit"> Add User </button>
</form>

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you saw the console warning about controlled fields needing an `onChange` handler and added one just to shut the warning up :)

If you replace your empty `onChange` handler functions with `onChange={this.handleChange}` and add this method to your component, it should work:

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

(Or for people not using an ES6 transpiler:)

```
handleChange: function(e) {
  var stateChange = {}
  stateChange[e.target.name] = e.target.value
  this.setState(stateChange)
}
```

However, if your component is an ES6 class extending `React.Component` (instead of using `React.createClass()`), you will also need to ensure the method is bound to the component instance properly, either in `render()`...

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

...or in the `constructor`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  // ...
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}
```